# Highlighting a row using html based on today's date

Tags: html, css

I am working on a tool where I have to format the results based on certain conditions. The first code works and displays records with very high rating in a different color. Can someone help me create a similar format when due date is prior to today's date as shown in code 2?

```
<tpl if='RATING=="Very High"'>
<div style="White-Space:Normal;Background-Color:#C00000;Color:White;Text-Align:Center;Line-Height:20px;"><b>{RATING}
 <tpl else>
{RATING}

 </tpl>    
<tpl if= DUEDATE &lt; {CURRENTDATE}>
<div style="White-Space:Normal;Background-Color:#C00000;Color:White;Text-Align:Center;Line-Height:20px;"><b>{DUEDATE}
<tpl else>
{DUEDATE}
</tpl>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest importing the moment.js library via script tag in head.

moment.js makes date calculations very easy.

Comment: Unfortunately the tool does not support that.